# Problema al conectar a MySQL desde PHP (Resuelto)

Tags: php, html, mysql

(RESUELTO. Tenia mal la contraseña)
Me sale este error al conectar: (he omitido user y pass por razones obvias)

> Access denied for user 'test'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)

```html
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "test", "password");

/* comprobar la conexión */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Conexión fallida: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

/* comprobar si el servidor sigue vivo */
if ($mysqli->ping()) {
    printf ("¡La conexión está bien!\n");
} else {
    printf ("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}

/* cerrar la conexión */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Buenas @Alejandro, deberías omitir también la IP. Dicho esto, parece que no tienes permisos en el usuario que estás intentando conectar, mira de poner los permisos necesarios a ése usuario y prueba de nuevo.

Comment: Voy a reportar la pregunta para ser cerrada, ya que era un error tipográfico

Comment: Igual que @amenadiel voto para cerrarla, ya que no aporta nada a la comunidad, por otro lado Alejandro dejarnos una letra/espacio en blanco nos ha pasado a tod@s. ;)

Comment: @Alejandro Por favor, no edites tu pregunta para añadir mensajes como "resuelto" o "la solución era..." Para eso están las respuestas (donde ya pusiste una). Además, el problema era un simple error tipográfico que es motivo de cierre de la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

El usuario y contraseña que has puesto son correctos??Normalmente el usuario es root ,y la contraseña es en blanco a no ser que la allas cambiado tu.

Prueba con esto a ver

```
    <?php
    // Ejemplo de conexión a base de datos MySQL con PHP.
    //


    // Datos de la base de datos
    $usuario = "root";
    $password = "";
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $basededatos = "alumnos";

    // creación de la conexión a la base de datos con mysql_connect()
    $conexion = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, "" ) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");

    // Selección del a base de datos a utilizar
    $db = mysqli_select_db( $conexion, $basededatos ) or die ( "Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos" );

mysqli_close( $conexion );
?>
```

Comment: Tema resuelto, me faltaba una letra en mi contraseña. que fallo...

Answer (score 1):

Si el usuario y la clave estan bien entonces el error como comentaba @Marc es por permisos, cuando instalas un motor de bd este se instala con permisos locales, así que debes crear el usuario ya sea desde tu administrador de base de datos o de la siguiente forma:

```
#Crear Usuario
CREATE USER 'nombre_usuario'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'tu_contrasena';

#Asignar Privilegios
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'nombre_usuario'@'localhost';
```

Cambia el `localhost` por la dirección IP de donde se va a conectar o podrias poner `%` para que se conecte desde cualquier dirección IP, pero debes tener encuenta que al usar `%` dejas expuesta la base ya que se podrian conectar desde cualquier parte a ella.

Si necesitas mas información para crear usuarios, te dejo este enlace:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/crear-un-nuevo-usuario-y-otorgarle-permisos-en-mysql-es

Comment: Tema resuelto, me faltaba una letra en mi contraseña. que fallo... me estaba volviendo loco buscando errores en el código y resulta que era la contraseña...